# How can i have 2 input link in DataStage sequence job?

Tags: etl, datastage

[image: My Sequence Job]

As you can see that when the SEQ_DIM_ACCOUNT Job executed it has 2 conditions with Success and Failure.
I wanted to run execute_command_60 when it's failed, but if execute_command_60 has been run, then i wanted the execute_command_60 to get to the SEQ_DIM_BUSINESS_PARTNER, but when i tried to link the execute_command_60 to SEQ_DIM_BUSINESS_PARTNER it gave me an error "the destination stage cannot support any more input links"

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible with the help of a [Sequencer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.design.doc/topics/r_ddesref_Examples_of_Using_Sequencer_Stage.html) stage.

Add that after the Execute_Command and before the SEQ_DIM_BUSINESS_PARTNER. This Stage kan take any number of Input-Links and you only have to specify if All or Any input links have been run to go on

Comment: Oh Okay that's really helpful! Thankyou so much, and can I make the XML Output format to be as i wanted?
In example the default format <column name> data </column name>
to be <column_name_1="data"   column_name_2="data2"></end tag>
Is it possible like to make edit the format via datastage?